# ASP Custom Server Control data flow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-customcontrol

I have to build a custom control where I will render a textbox where I am supposed to take input, and on textbox change event I will have to keep a list of objects that satisfy that search string I took from the input, which should be exposed to be fetched at any time. I have no idea how to make an asynchronous call to the code behind the control. I am very new to custom controls, recently I have developed only one that rendered some div. I am very confused about this one, can any one give me any idea of how to do this? I am not asking for the code, I can figure it on my own, but I am missing the idea or general knowledge about asp custom controls.

Comment: It's simple you need to add some js to the control you rendering, that will do what you need to do async, if you need any code examples I will gladly post it, after I get back home.

Comment: I really need some examples. I tried rendering a couple of controls inside an updatepanel, with thier events bound, but none of them fire. Infact, on button clicks it is posting back which is weird as i put them in an updatepanel.

Comment: OK couple of things, button will fire an event because it's behavior on with in the 'form' it's causes a submit.
What you need to do is, to attach an attribute [autopostback=true]

Comment: Ok, going to try it now.

Comment: but my original problem is there, i put these controls inside an update panel, but behavior tells it doesnt render it right.

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: i have also added another question, the code is pasted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240094/buttons-on-click-event-inside-an-update-panel-rendered-through-a-custom-server